# Slow Ruby for simple array operations

Tags: ruby, performance

I created simple insertion sort implementation in Ruby, following pseudo-code from Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms":

```
def sort_insert(array)
  (1 ... array.length).each do |item_index|
    key = array[item_index]
    i = item_index - 1

    while i >= 0 && array[i] > key do
      array[i + 1] = array[i]
      i -= 1
    end
    array[i + 1] = key
  end
  array
end
```

It works, but performs very slowly. For ~20k elements array `array = ((0..10_000).to_a * 2).shuffle`, it takes about 20 seconds to sort. I measure time only for this method call, no data preparation etc. In JavaScript, a very similar solution to this takes about 1 second. Why is Ruby (v. 2.2.2p95) so slow here?

Edit:
JS version of this sorting, which I use:

```
function SortMethods() {
}

SortMethods.prototype.sortInsert = function(array) {
  for(let itemIndex = 1; itemIndex < array.length; itemIndex++) {
    let key = array[itemIndex];
    let i = itemIndex - 1;

    while( i >= 0 && array[i] > key) {
      array[i + 1] = array[i];
      i--;
    }
    array[i + 1] = key;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Ruby?

Comment: ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [i686-linux]

Comment: Do you have default GC settings?

Comment: It takes about 5.9 seconds on my laptop to sort 20k random numbers (`a = Array.new(20_000) { rand }`).  Can't compare to JS, since I'm not a JS programmer, but I don't find ~6 seconds shocking for an O(N^2) algorithm w/ 20k values.  By contrast, using `a.sort!` takes 0.01 seconds, plenty fast for me to do real work.

Comment: for me this questions sounds like, "why does my knife not cut, if I use it upside down"

Comment: You can use [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof) to get a sense of how Ruby is spending its time.  But it shouldn't be surprising that there is a 20x difference in speed between two implementations of different languages.  You do not even say what Javascript implementation is being used so it will be very hard to comment on the differences.

Comment: @Anatoly: yes, GC is enabled: $ ruby -e 'puts GC.enable' shows 'false'

Comment: I think the question as posed is fundamentally not answerable, or at least not in any useful or meaningful way.  The correct but useless answer to "Why is A not the same as B?" is "Because A and B are different."

Comment: In my mac mini, the code written in ruby took 10.14 secs, the code written in javascript (ran in browser) took 6.84 secs. I don't think javascript can take only one sec.

Comment: @user5132946 Please include the Ruby version in the question itself. Also, include the benchmarks you _expect_, and where you get that expectation from. Is it from running a similar operation in JavaScript?

Comment: @HunterStevens yes, I've written JS version of the same algorithm and said I wonder why Ruby implementation is so much slower compared to Javascript. I included both codes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with the premise of your question—Ruby is turning in more than respectable performance on my machine.

To illustrate this, I created a file with 100k random numbers:

```
$ ruby -e '100_000.times {printf "%22.20f\n", rand}' > rand100k.csv
```

I then sorted this with the system sort utility, saving the results for later comparison (as a correctness check):

```
$ time sort -n < rand100k.csv > foo

real    0m0.067s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.011s
```

I wrote a quicksort algorithm (which flips over to insertion sort when the sublist size gets small enough) in pure ruby, ran it, saved the results, and diff'ed the system sort output and ruby output files:

```
$ time ruby quicksort_w_insertion.rb < rand100k.csv > bar

real    0m0.546s
user    0m0.537s
sys 0m0.008s
$ diff foo bar
$
```

As you can see, both sorting runs produce identical output, and very quickly.  In my opinion, a pure Ruby program which is only 8-10 times slower than the corresponding system utility is doing mighty darn fine speed-wise.

These runs were made with `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50293) [x86_64-darwin14]` on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question. My question was why Ruby's implementation of simple insertion sorting is much slower than analogous implementation in JavaScript. So comparing Ruby with OS utility is improper. Perhaps writing quick sort in JS and then comparing with Ruby implementation could give a some clue.

Comment: I disagree.  What you're asking requires us to assume a whole bunch of things are similar, including your implementation of the sorting algorithm, what behaviors the interpreters are using, optimization of the build, dependence on internal vs system libraries during the build of ruby and JS interpreters, etc., etc.

Comment: (Sorry, a student came in for office hours.)  Your experience doesn't support the thesis that Ruby as a language is intrinsically slow - I've given a counterexample showing otherwise.  I'm actually pretty amazed that an interpreted language can turn in run times within an order of magnitude of a system utility. To me that shows that the issue is probably one of implementation, possibly in the ports of the languages to your system, possibly because attempts at verbatim translations from one language to another don't work any better for computer languages than for human ones.

Comment: I've never said that Ruby is slow language - I said Ruby is slow for this algorithm compared to JavaScript. I don't requite assumptions about how interpreters works etc. - I just want to know why it is. Possibly interpreter optimization or how the programming language store array in memory is the answer, but I don't know - that's why I asked this question.

Comment: If it's because of interpreter optimization, or anything else specific to **your installation**, there's no way for anybody else to know.